# How to Obtain Google Quotes in KMyMoney?

Tags: accounting, google-finance, stockquotes, google-finance-api

In order to retrieve the stock quote from Google Finance in KMyMoney do the following:

1. Goto https://finance.google.com and obtain the symbol, example "NASDAQ:GOOG"
2. Open KMyMoney, goto Settings->Configure kMyMoney->Online Quotes
3. Click on the "New" and give the following settings:

URL:   http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=%1
Symbol: %1
Price:  "l_fix" : "(\d+.\d+)"
Date: "lt_dts" : "(.\d+-\d\d-\d\d)
Date format: %y %m %d

Click on the button "Update".  Double click to rename this entry.

In the investment entry page, associate this quoting source.  Ensure the symbol is inclusive of the source like NASDAQ:GOOG

To update the quotes, click on the "Tools->Update Stock and Currency Prices".

Answer (score -1):

In order to retrieve the stock quote from Google Finance in KMyMoney do the following:

1. Goto https://finance.google.com and obtain the symbol, example "NASDAQ:GOOG"
2. Open KMyMoney, goto Settings->Configure kMyMoney->Online Quotes
3. Click on the "New" and give the following settings:

URL:   https://finance.google.com/finance?q=%1
Symbol: %1
Price:  "l_fix" : "(\d+.\d+)"
Date: "lt_dts" : "(.\d+-\d\d-\d\d)
Date format: %y %m %d

Click on the button "Update".  Double click to rename this entry.

In the investment entry page, associate this quoting source.  Ensure the symbol is inclusive of the source like NASDAQ:GOOG

To update the quotes, click on the "Tools->Update Stock and Currency Prices".